# How to remove my ex's name on my title

Tags: title

My truck title has mine and my ex's name on it. It is paid for but she moved out of state and I have no way to contact her or even find her. How can I get her name removed from my title since I'm unable to have her fill out or sign anything

Comment: This could be location dependent. Let us know the country/state.

Comment: This is a legal question, as you are going to need to have her ownership of part of your truck nullified.

Comment: If both names are on the title then it isn't your truck.  It's a truck owned jointly by you and your ex.  If she has one half ownership in the truck, you aren't rellistically going to be able to transfer her ownership to you without her authorization.

Comment: You will also have a problem when you want to sell the vehicle.

Comment: Does it say you AND her or you OR her?

Comment: Often issues such as this are detailed in a divorce agreement.  Have you checked that?  That agreement, under a court's order, should be able to be used at your motor vehicle bureau to obtain a title in your name only.